# how to separate the low and high frequency components of an image by torch.fft?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, fft

I want to separate the low and high frequency components of an image by `torch.fft`.

It would be better to give me a sample like this:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
f = np.fft.fft2(img)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)

rows, cols = img.shape
crow,ccol = rows/2 , cols/2
fshift[crow-30:crow+30, ccol-30:ccol+30] = 0
f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift)
img_back = np.fft.ifft2(f_ishift)
img_back = np.abs(img_back)
```

Comment: why? wouldn't that be simpler using a LPF on the image itself? isn't it exactly like laplacian pyramid?